# Why JdbcTemplate.batchupdate(sql[]) method not roll back in Spring4 using @transaction annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

The below code is not working for rollback when any exception occurs while insertion of records in database.I am using Spring 4 framework and annotation .

*/*I am using below code for transaction management and  it will not roll back for any exception.*/

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)
public boolean insertBatch(List<String> query) throws SQLException   {
    boolean flag= false;
    try
    {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        String[] Sql= query.toArray(new String[query.size()]);
        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(Sql);

        flag=true;

    }catch(DataAccessException e )
    {
        flag=false;
        MessageResource.setMessages("Constraints Violation ! CSV data value not matched with database constraints  ");
        LOGGER.info("CSV file Data not  expected as  database table structure defination like constraint violation/Data Type lenght/NUll etc for same data value" );
        LOGGER.error( "Cause for error:  "+  e.getRootCause().getMessage());
        LOGGER.debug( "Details explain : "+  e.toString());
        throw new RuntimeException("Roll back operation");
        //transactionManager.rollback(status);

    }
         return flag;


}**
```

Comment: I would use a simple empty `@Transactional` and simply rethrow the exception (`DataAccessException` is a `RuntimeException`) also you are losing the context (as you are ignoring the original exception). Next instead of creating your own `JdbcTemplate` you should inject one (or at least create a single instance of it). Finally make sure that you use a database that supports transactions MySQL with MyISAM tables for instance doesn't support transactions. I'm also wondering how this method is called as if this is an internal method call the `@Transactional` is useless.

Comment: Sir, Thanks for suggestion,but i ddnot understand clearly what i am missing here. Please provide some example via code or modifiy above code. I ll be greatfull to you.

Comment: What is it you don't understand?

Comment: Sir, i tried  your way simply re throw the exception but not working . I am not understand  that if it is internal method call means. yea its called from another method in same class . if it is problem then how to over come ,  FYI  i m new  in spring . Thanks

Comment: Spring uses proxies to apply AOP this will only work for methods called from the outside. Internal method calls don't pass through the proxy hence no transactions and depending on your queries you get one large or multiple smaller commits. Make sure that the outer method (the one called to initiate everything) is transactional.

Comment: Thanks for such a nice explanation .I understand the concept. I will keep all transnational method in DAo class and invoke it from other services or component .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the answer provided by Sir, M.Deinum is below:

Spring uses proxies to apply AOP this will only work for methods called from the outside. Internal method calls don't pass through the proxy hence no transactions and depending on your queries you get one large or multiple smaller commits. Make sure that the outer method (the one called to initiate everything) is transactional. –  M. Deinum 14 hours ago

Answer (score 0):

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)
```

This will rollback *only if a RuntimeException or a subclass is thrown* from the annotated method. If you want to rollback for any `Exception` (such as `SQLException`, which is **NOT** a `RuntimeException`), you should do:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

And if you want to try a rollback for whatever error that might happen

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
```

Altough in this last case the runtime might be so broken that not even the rollback can complete.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I had tried this but still not working for Exception.class . What thing  i am missing . It insert 8 record before exception and when exception occur on 9 th record then it will not rollbacked for previous inserted record using above code.

Answer (score 0):

Use Prepared statement from connection object and the do a execute batch object. On the connection object use conn.setAutoCommit(false). Prepeared statement has 4 times better performance than JdbcTemplate for batch insertion of 1000 records.

Reference : [JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate() returns 0, on insert error for one item but inserts the remaining item into sql server db despite using @Transactional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70974845/jdbctemplate-batchupdate-returns-0-on-insert-error-for-one-item-but-inserts-t/70997232#70997232)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30995387)